# Highcharts calculated max value not working with 2+ Y axis

Tags: highcharts

I have been stuck on this for a while now and despite several attempts and a lot of research I have yet to find the solution.
I am building charts with two Y axis. Everything works just fine except that the highcharts computed max Y value is always much higher than it should be. Resulting in a zoomed out graph.
I've replicated the problem here : http://jsfiddle.net/9vmtz3nf/

I cannot hardcode any max value as it will always depend on the data coming in from the DB and there is a very wide margin of values possible.

So basically, how can I tweak the options and parameters to make sure the graph max value is set to the closest tick (150/600 in the jsfiddle example) ?

Thank you in advance

```
$(function () {
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: [{
            title: {
                text: 'Primary Axis'
            },
        }, {
            title: {
                text: 'Secondary Axis'
            },
            opposite: true
        }],
        plotOptions: {
        },
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 124.0, 126.0, 135.6, 111.5, 116.4, 114.1, 95.6, 54.4]

        }, {
            data: [129.9, 271.5, 306.4, 29.2, 544.0, 376.0, 435.6, 348.5, 216.4, 294.1, 35.6, 354.4],
            yAxis: 1

        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a result of the chart trying to find a common denominator. Even if you do hard code a `max` value, the chart will behave this way.

Setting the `alignTicks` property to `false` will fix this.

```
chart: {
  alignTicks: false
}
```

Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/9vmtz3nf/2/

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.alignTicks

Comment: Thanks jlbrrigs. I have played around with alignTicks already and yes it works in the sense that the max tick is set properly but it doesn't look good at all (even if I hide the second axis gridlines).
I understand the common denominator logic but it doesn't explain why in my example this is not 150/600 ? None of the values go beyond that threshold

Comment: In my example, it *is* 150/600, so I am somewhat confused what else you want it to do, and what doesn't look good?

Comment: In your example the right Y axis labels are well aligned (despite the alignTicks being turned off) but most of the time it is not the case. You would have the right labels not in front of gridlines, which does not look good :/